# How can I stop bots from using my smart contract?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ether, dapps

My use case involves a contract with a fixed prize pool, users interact with the contract by making a payment and receiving a reward, I made it so in the long term the reward is greater than the cost, this in order to distribute the tokens. That's why I dont want bots to buy a whole chunk of it, I want to keep the contract alive for a while so users can play.

Is there any way to stop a bot from using this kind of smart contract?

Comment: After reading a lot I figured out that it's not possible to do this now. The only way to stop bots is to make the contract the most unexploitable possible. i.e. a contract that's not profitable for the user

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do is to use a whitelist, and only allow certain users to use the smart contract. This may not be user-friendly to many users if you wanted your contract to be opened and used by anybody.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Contract {

    address public owner;
    mapping(address => bool) /*public?*/ whitelist;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Sender does not have permission");
        _;
    }

    modifier whitelisted() {
        require(whitelist[msg.sender], "The sender is not whitelisted");
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function addToWhiteList(address userAddress) public onlyOwner {
        whitelist[userAddress] = true;
    }

    function removeFromWhitelist(address userAddress) public onlyOwner {
        delete whitelist[userAddress];
    }

    function doSomething() public whitelisted {
        // Doing something that only a whitelisted user can do
    }

    // Rest of the code

}
```

Or you could only allow certain calls per certain time for a specific address. Let's say, 1 call after 1 minute to a certain address, saving the `block.timestamp` and checking it.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at CAPTCHA solutions such as geetest’s, if you have a front end site for that smart contract.

Comment: This may stop bots that use the frontend, but it will not help with bots that interact with the contract directly.